# What are the supernatural properties of gold in mythology and folklore?

Tags: comparative, folklore

I would like to research the supernatural properties and/or uses that gold shows in mythologies and/or folklore.

I am not talking about the properties or abilities of specific artifacts made of gold or named after gold (like the Golden Apples of Idun that made a person younger, or the gold ring of Odin which would create copies of itself), but of the inherent properties and/or abilties of the substance of gold itself; supernatural properties just as gold has the physical property of being a great conductor of electricity, and supernatural/magic uses of gold like the technological use of gold as a conductor in electronics.

I am aware of gold's general association with eternity and the divine (inspired by it's color and resistance to corrosion), but I'd like some concrete examples, like the story of how silver would change in the presence of poison and thus was used to make drinking cups for the rich and paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

The topic is vast but as a starting place I would suggest George B. Kauffman, Gold Bulletin 1985(18)p.31–44, [The role of gold in alchemy. Part I](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF03214684.pdf).